# how to avoid duplicated .pipe() on gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, dry

On my gulpfile.js I have some tasks that have some `.pipes()` in common. Right now i copy/paste them where I need but ideally I want to avoid _*WET - write everything twice.*

An example:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    console.log('start task scripts');
    gulp.src([
            folderScripts+'/**/*.js',
            '!'+folderScripts+'/**/_*.js',
            '!'+folderScripts+'/**/*.min.js'
        ])

        // some .pipes() here

        // --- FIXME Find a way to not duplicate this
        .pipe(include())
            .on('error', console.log)
        .pipe(gulpif(argv.production, stripDebug()))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        // --- END FIXME Find a way to not duplicate this

        //more .pipes()

        .pipe(gulp.dest('exported'));
    logEnv();
});


gulp.task('min-this', function(){
    // some code

   if (argv.js || argv.jsfolder) {

     gulp.src([
        argv.js ? argv.js
        : argv.jsfolder+'/**/*.js',
        '!'+argv.jsfolder+'/**/_*.js',
        '!'+argv.jsfolder+'/**/*.min.js'
        ])

        // some .pipes() here 

        // --- FIXME Find a way to not duplicate this
         .pipe(include())
            .on('error', console.log)
        .pipe(gulpif(argv.production, stripDebug()))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        // --- END FIXME Find a way to not duplicate this

        //more .pipes()

        .pipe(gulp.dest( function(file) { return file.base; } ));
   }
});
```

How can I not duplicate what is inside the block `// --- FIXME Find a way to not duplicate this` ?

Thanks

Comment: What if you just have `function commonPipes(stuff) {return stuff.pipe().pipe().pipe()}`?

Comment: can you show an example with the code i provided?

Comment: I tried something like that but i always had sintax errors, couldn't figure out a way

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure myself, it was a genuine question - it _seems_ like it should be possible but I don't know if it is. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Hmm, it's not as straight forward as I thought. At least in part because I'm not familiar enough with Gulp and for some reason I can't easily find the info on the API for the `.pipe` - I was thinking that it should be easy to just pipe into your custom function that does more stuff then returns the data for you to continue piping. However, I did find [this article](http://paulsalaets.com/posts/reusable-pipelines-in-gulp-build) which seems to be what you want. There also seem to be few plugins for Gulp that make what you want easier.

Comment: Hmm thanks, i'll take a look and then i'll let you know if it worked